# SpellCheckerService - unable to find actual spell checking logic

Tags: java, android, android-source

I have always admired Android's `SpellCheckerService`, and am trying to lift its logic into a webapp.

In browsing the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/service/textservice/SpellCheckerService.java#SpellCheckerService.SentenceLevelAdapter.SentenceTextInfoParams) for `SpellCheckerService`, my impression is that a lot of the heavy lifting is done by `SuggestionsInfo`, which returns a list of suggested possible spelling for a mis-typed word.

However, examining the `SuggestionsInfo` framework's own [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/textservice/SuggestionsInfo.java#SuggestionsInfo) shows not much logic code in terms of performing the actual spell checking. Any associated dictionaries (which are needed in the case of Hunspell or Lucene) also are not referenced. Am I missing something?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I found a bunch of nasty native code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/native/jni/src/suggest/core/ actual dictionaries seem to be in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/dictionaries/

Comment: @zapl Perfect! It seems these "nasty code" is just what I needed.